# How to get the frequency of each element in array from all rows in table in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a table of 2 columns and N rows like below,

```sql
email | phone_num_list
----------------------
'a'   | {"1", "2", "3"}
'a'   | {"1", "4"}
'c'   | {"5", "1", "6"}
'd'   | {"3", "7", "1"}
```

where `phone_num_list` is of type array.

My requirement is to get the most used phone numbers and their scores, where **score** = `number of distinct email associated with the phone_num * total frequency of phone_num`

Hence, for the above example, distinct emails associated with phone_num **`1`** are **`["a", "c", "d"]`**.

Hence, the score of phone_num **`1`** is `3(i.e total distinct emails) * 4(i.e total frequency of 1)`

Calculation of score for all the phone_num is written below -

```
phone_num | distinct emails associated | freq of phone_num | final_score
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1      |     ["a", "c", "d"]        |      4            |   4*3 = 12
   2      |     ["a"]                  |      1            |   1*1 = 1
   3      |     ["a", "d"]             |      2            |   2*2 = 4
   4      |     ["a"]                  |      1            |   1*1 = 1
   5      |     ["c"]                  |      1            |   1*1 = 1
   6      |     ["c"]                  |      1            |   1*1 = 1
   7      |     ["d"]                  |      1            |   1*1 = 1
```

My desired output is ->

```sql
phone | score
-------------
 1    | 12
 3    | 4
 2    | 1 
 4    | 1
 5    | 1
 6    | 1
 7    | 1
```

Please help me with the query in PostgreSql.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preparing the test case:

```sql
create temporary table t (email text, phone_num_list text[]);
insert into t(email, phone_num_list) values
('a', '{"1", "2", "3"}'),
('a', '{"1", "4"}'),
('c', '{"5", "1", "6"}'),
('d', '{"3", "7", "1"}');
```

'Normalize' the table into `nt` CTE and then calculate the frequency times the number of distinct emails per phone number.

```sql
with nt as (select email, unnest(phone_num_list) as phone from t)
select phone, count(*) * count(distinct email) as score
from nt group by phone order by score desc;
```

```
phone|score|
-----+-----+
1    |   12|
3    |    4|
5    |    1|
6    |    1|
7    |    1|
4    |    1|
2    |    1|
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "unnest" function.

```
    select phone_number, 
    count(phone_number) * count(distinct email) as score
    from
        (
        select email, unnest(phone_num_list) as phone_number
        from t1
        )z
    group by 1
    order by 2 desc
```

db-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8TsPEDcmNZp9t4E3xjBxyR/0):

Comment: This query looks simple. Thanks for the quick response!